# jQuery animating to left goes out of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With the following function, I can animate a div to the left, but the problem is that, the div goes out of the screen area. Is there anyway that I can keep the `#mydiv` to go to the left within the `#container` only? If `#mydiv` is already on the left side, then it should just do nothing.

```
 $('.left').click(function() {
        $('#myDiv').animate({
            left: '-=30'
            }, 400, function() {
            // callBack
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
        <a class="left" href="#">Left</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to obtain this you need to verify that the div you want to move is positioned at least `30px` from the `left` side of you `#container`.

```
$('.left').click(function() {
if (parseInt($('#myDiv').css('left')) >= 30) {     
    $('#myDiv').animate({
        left: '-=30'
        }, 400, function() {
        // callBack
    });

     }
 });
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/X2TdJ/1/

If your `#container` will be positioned to the left of you body `marginLeft` will not stop and go outside of your `#container` div.

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/DAEsX/1/

Comment: Thanks, your answer was helpful, but I'm trying to add another link to scroll to right, and it does not work then. could you please have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/X2TdJ/3/

Comment: this is a raw code of what you want to obtain [http://jsfiddle.net/X2TdJ/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/X2TdJ/5/). It does  the job but it needs a lot of refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `margin-left: -30px;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To limit in the area of container you could try:

```
$('.left').click(function() {
    if($('#myDiv').offset().left != 0){ //could be >= 0
        $('#myDiv').animate({
            marginLeft: '-=30'
            }, 400);
    }else{
        console.log('left - 0');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    margin-left: 150px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <a class="left" href="#">Left</a>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</div>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DAEsX/)

Comment: @user1355300 the fiddle seem to works for me, because the margin is multiple of 30, if is not you could try >= 0 in the offset.